# Issue with AttributeError in PyTorch TransformerEncoderLayer

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

Description:

Hello everyone,

I am encountering an issue while working with PyTorch's TransformerEncoderLayer, and I'm seeking some assistance from the community to resolve it.

Problem:
I am attempting to use PyTorch's TransformerEncoderLayer in my code, specifically in the context of a Transformer-based model. However, when I try to run the code, I encounter the following AttributeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/A_projects/Python/expTest/train.py", line 208, in <module>
    train_eval(epoch)
  File "E:/A_projects/Python/expTest/train.py", line 127, in train_eval
    rppg = model(video)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\A_projects\Python\expTest\models\Sformer.py", line 130, in forward
    features = self.temporal_encoder(x)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\A_projects\Python\expTest\models\Sformer.py", line 46, in forward
    token = self.transformer_enc(x)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\transformer.py", line 388, in forward
    output = mod(output, src_mask=mask, is_causal=is_causal,
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\transformer.py", line 707, in forward
    if self.norm_first:
  File "D:\CondaVirtualEnvironment\envs\cuda118py38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1695, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: 'TransformerEncoderLayer' object has no attribute 'norm_first'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Context:
The error occurs when I call the forward() method of my model, which includes a TransformerEncoderLayer. It seems to be related to an attribute called norm_first, which is not recognized by the TransformerEncoderLayer class.

Request for Help:
I have reviewed the PyTorch documentation and other resources, but I'm unable to identify the cause of this error. I'm reaching out to the community for assistance in understanding why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it.

Additional Information:

I am using PyTorch version 2.1.0.
The code snippet where the error occurs is related to the application of the TransformerEncoderLayer within my model's forward pass.
I have also checked for any potential issues with my installation or environment, but everything seems to be in order.
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best regards!
[image: Related codes]

I have tried many methods but none of them have solved the problem. I beg the experts to help me clarify.

---

I have organized the code, and below is a simplified portion of it. I have annotated the part that is causing the error.

This is the code for the training section:

```
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'TRUE'

'''
Due to space constraints, only the relevant key code for the training part is retained here.
'''

ac_train = AC_RPPG(video_length=video_length, image_size=img_size, source_file=ac_train_source_file,
                       base_dir=ac_base_dir, target_fps=target_fps, bvp_length=bvp_length)

train_dataset = MergedSet([ac_train])

# dataloader
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

model = RPPGSFormer(num_frames=video_length * target_fps, signal_length=bvp_length)

model = model.to(device)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_eval(epoch)


def train_eval(epoch):
    global eval_times, best_model, min_eval_loss
    epoch_loss = 0.
    start_time = time.time()
    for batch_id, (video, bvp, hr, fps, bvp_sampling_rate) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # to device
        video = video.float().to(device)
        bvp = bvp.float().to(device)

        # predict
        # The code encountered an error at this point in execution,
        # and the error message describes the specific issue mentioned in this problem.
        rppg = model(video)
```

This is the structural code related to the model:

```
class RPPGSFormer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_frames=96, signal_length=96, pretrained=True, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed_dim = 192
        self.signal_length = signal_length
        self.vit = VisionTransformer(patch_size=16, embed_dim=192, depth=12, num_heads=3, mlp_ratio=4,
                                     qkv_bias=True, norm_layer=partial(nn.LayerNorm, eps=1e-6), **kwargs)
        if pretrained:
            path = r'E:\A_projects\Python\expTest\saved_models\deit_tiny_patch16_224-a1311bcf.pth'
            checkpoint = torch.load(path)
            self.vit.load_state_dict(checkpoint["model"])
        self.vit.head = nn.Identity()
        self.temporal_encoder = TemporalEncoder(clip_length=num_frames, embed_dim=self.embed_dim, n_layers=6)

        # Omit part of the code...

    def forward(self, x):
        '''
            x.shape == [B, C, T, H, W]
        '''
        B, C, T, H, W = x.shape
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3, 4)
        x = x.reshape(B * T, C, H, W)  # [B*T, 3, H, W]
        x = self.vit(x)  # [B*T, 192]

        features = self.temporal_encoder(x)
        rppg = self.head(features)
        return rppg

def trunc_normal_(x, mean=0., std=1.): 
    return x.normal_().fmod_(2).mul_(std).add_(mean)

class TemporalEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, clip_length=None, embed_dim=2048, n_layers=6):
        super(TemporalEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.clip_length = clip_length
        enc_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=embed_dim, nhead=8)

        # The error can be traced back to this point.
        self.transformer_enc = nn.TransformerEncoder(enc_layer, num_layers=n_layers, norm=nn.LayerNorm(embed_dim))
        # ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
        
        self.cls_token = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, 1, embed_dim))
        self.pos_embed = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, clip_length + 1, embed_dim))
        with torch.no_grad():
            trunc_normal_(self.pos_embed, std=.02)
            trunc_normal_(self.cls_token, std=.02)
        self.apply(self._init_weights)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.shape[0] // self.clip_length
        x = x.reshape((batch_size, self.clip_length, -1))
        cls_tokens = self.cls_token.expand(batch_size, -1, -1)
        x = torch.cat((cls_tokens, x), dim=1)  # [B, T+1, D]
        x = x + self.pos_embed
        x.transpose_(1, 0)

        # The error can be traced back to this point.
        token = self.transformer_enc(x)
        return token[0]
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.